# programmatic dropzone not showing icons

Tags: jquery, dropzone.js

I using dropzone v4.0.0 and I'm loading some HTML dynamically to programamatically attach dropzone to.

The HTML looks like this:

```
<div id="dz"></div>
```

My CSS for #dz looks like this

```
#dz{
    margin-bottom:15px;
    width:calc(100% - 30px);
    height:200px;
    background:#f2f2f2; 
    text-align:center;
    line-height:200px;
}
```

I also have dropzone.css loading in my  HTML file header.

After the page loads, I want to programmatically attach a dropzone to it.
I'm doing it like this:

```
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
myDropzone = new Dropzone("#dz", { 
        url: "cgi/fileUpload.exe",
        maxFilesize:4,
        dictDefaultMessage:"drop files here or click to choose"
});
```

My dropzone works as far as being able to drag files into it or click and browse for files, but the dropzone icons don't show, nor do the X and checkmark on bad or good uploads. The information on the file upload goes way down the page, past the height of #dz. I'm not getting errors.

Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to create a form and and attach to the div #dv

```
var dz='<form action="cgi/fileUploader.exe" ';
dz+='         class="dropzone"';            
dz+='         id="my-dropzone">';
dz+='</form>';  

$("#dz").html(dz);

setTimeout(function(){               
      Dropzone.autoDiscover = false; 
      var myDropzone = new Dropzone("#my-dropzone");
},500);
```